# Cannot access state by getters vuex vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am new to vuex I want to access user object that is inside in state by the getters getUser() method, I tried to call this
**console.log(this.$store.getters.getUser);** in mounted method but no results.
I tried to console log inside mutations and it return the user object.
I also followed documentations and googled the solutions but nothing happen

What else am I missing?

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    user: {},
},
getters: {
    getUser: state => {
       return state.user
     }
    
},
mutations: {
    auth_user(state,data) {
        state.user = data
    }
 },
actions: {
    fetchAuthUser(context){
        axios.get('/user-data').then(response => {
            context.commit("auth_user",response.data)
        }).catch({});
    }
}, 

 })


 export default store
```

Index.js

```
  mounted(){
  // this.auth_user;
   this.getCategories();
   this.$store.dispatch('fetchAuthUser', this.auth_user);
    console.log(this.$store.getters.getUser);
},
```

Comment: try `console.log(this.$store.state.state.user)`

Answer (score 1):

Your action is async and should return a promise.

```
fetchAuthUser(context){
    return axios.get('/user-data').then(response => {
        context.commit("auth_user",response.data)
    }).catch({});
}
```

In your mounted you can use `then` to handle data.

```
mounted(){
   // this.auth_user;
   this.getCategories();
   this.$store.dispatch('fetchAuthUser', this.auth_user).then(() => {
      console.log(this.$store.getters.getUser);
   });
}
```

Comment: then please consider accepting the answer.